# Параметризированный метод для Class<T>

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть интерфейс Animal и 2 класса реализующих этот интерфейс : Dog и Cat

Я хочу создать метод использующий параметризированную рефлексию (я делаю так):

```
public static Animal create(String name, Class<Animal> myClass){
      return myClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class}).newInstance(name);
}
```

Но в main я не могу передать в метод Dog.class, почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш метод принимает только `Animal`

используйте `Class<? extend Animal> myClass` - так вы укажите что метод может принимать классы `Animal` и любых наследников `Animal`

Comment: Если Интерфейс?

Comment: если интерфейс!

Comment: Можете пояснить, почему для интерфейса это тоже работает?

Comment: немогу, честно, т.к. я не понимаю почему не должно работать. Объясните почему не должно.

Comment: extends ключевое слово для класса

Comment: Dog например не наследует Animal

Comment: ну если не наследует, то в метод и не зайдет, компиляция выкинет ошибку. extends это ключевое слово наследования. Когда вы пишите интерфейс, который наследует другой интерфейс вы пишите                interfsce First extends Last

Comment: чат https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68832